# Java DB issue with OSGi and JPA - SpringProxy not visible

Tags: java, spring, jpa, osgi

My application is using Spring (STS) and OSGi. The DB layer uses JPA (with Eclipse-Link), I have:

- one OSGi project for my DAO
- one OSGi project for my DAO implementations

Since the Entity Manager was not committing my changes as in [this other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/374886/spring-hibernate-jpa-calling-persist-on-entitymanager-does-not-seem-to-commit), I added the `@Transactional` annotation in my DAO objects for my create, update and delete methods (if I understood well, the read-only methods such as find are not concerned).

But this raises an exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: interface org.springframework.aop.SpringProxy
is not visible from class loader
```

I added the annotation at DAO and DAO impl levels first, then only at DAO Impl level, but the result is the same. I'm sometimes a bit lost with Spring, could you please help ?

Thanks !

Comment: DAOs shouldn't be @Transactional. Put @Transactional on the service layer that uses the DAOs

Comment: You're totally true ! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was actually an OSGi issue: OSGi is made of bundles, each one executes in its own environment and one of my module was lacking visibility on another one.

To fix this, we had to use [AOP and weaving](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming).

Comment: . Can you please let me know how you resolved this issue?I'm facing similar error while trying to start my bundle.I'm using @Transaction annotation, but my understanding is that its supported by spring-tx module (org.springframework.transaction) and not aop. I'll appreciate if you can provide some pointers.

Comment: Since you used @Transactional annotation, that means you enabled annotation-driven transaction, that relies on AOP. Some transaction related code will be injected automatically.